# Paramtrizing a complex arc

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you paramatrize the semi circle with radius 1 about the orgin from the initial point i to -i in the counterclockwise direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard formula 
$$
e^ {i \theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta
$$
to see that you can use the following arc:
$$
\theta \mapsto \cos(\theta)-i\sin( \theta)
$$
where $\theta \in [ -\pi/2 , \pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

If I told you to parametrize the semi circle with radius $1$ centered in the origin, going from $(0,1)$ to $(0,-1)$, in the counterclockwise direction, could you do it?

I think you would probably tell me to do: $$\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t), \quad  -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

The catch is that $\Bbb C \cong \Bbb R^2$ via $1 \equiv (1,0)$ and $i \equiv (0,1)$. So: $$\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t) = \cos t \cdot (1,0) + \sin t \cdot (0,1) = \cos t + i \sin t = e^{it},$$ where the last $=$ is due to Euler's formula.